# Does Internet Explorer have something equivalent to Chrome's app mode?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Can I open a browser window in Internet Explorer for a specific website without having any tabs, toolbars, bookmarks, etc.?

Just the window border and the site, that's it. I want something like Chrome's "App Mode", but for Internet Explorer. Is there a command-line switch for Internet Explorer or something similar that will open a specific site without any browser stuff in the window?

Otherwise, is there any small program I can use that would accomplish the same thing? (Like something that just does nothing but open a window with an Internet Explorer renderer in it.)

Information on any version of Internet Explorer is useful.

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean that this is something launched from a link on a web site.  Picture a shortcut on the local desktop that launches Internet Explorer to a specific site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[HTML applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=VS.85).aspx) are .hta files that contain normal HTML. When you open them, just a window frame is drawn around the page. But beware, HTA files run [without the security settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=VS.85).aspx#security) that Internet Explorer normally uses.

(HTA is meant for *programmers* to create applications using HTML and scripting languages, so HTAs are able to access files and things that normal webpages can't. Chrome's application shortcuts are meant for *users* to make websites more like programs on the desktop. So they're not quite the same thing.)

For example, you can save the following text into a file called google.hta

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Google</title>
</head>
<frameset>
<frame src="http://www.google.com/" application="no">
</frameset>
</html>
```

According to the [security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=VS.85).aspx#security) section, the `application="no"` attribute turns on the Internet Explorer security settings.

I've only used hta for small HTML-only files I made myself, so I could be sure they contained no scripts. If you're making your own HTML files, you might also decide to use an HTA file as a shortcut to remove the clutter of the Internet Explorer window. If you want to open internet websites in an HTA file, you might need to be careful.

Comment: If you change it to <frameset style="border-style: none;"> you can get rid of the double border.

Comment: The example does not seem to work as Google (and quite a few other sites) don't allow their pages to be displayed in a frame *(see [error message](http://i.imgur.com/8uRMXix.png))* - using `http://en.wikipedia.org` as the link seems to work though. Thanks, worked for what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I know you can full screen IE by pressing F11 but no borders are shown and also you can Right Click on the dashboard where the bookmarks tab is an de-select all the options shown but you'll still see the URL Bar and the Tab bar.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to launch it with a specific web page loaded, not to interact with IE in such a way to achieve this state.  IE should still be useable as before, without changing any options in other windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you would need to have direct access to the file system to edit the settings in the browser which isn't permitted without the users consent. I don't think it's possible to do all from the cloud. You'd have to write an application that would be downloaded and launched on the users computer. It's going take a lot of work :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to imply that I want to do this from a web page.  I want to do this from something executed locally.